# How to plot histogram of difference of two images using MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, histogram

i would like to calculate difference of two images. Then, histogram of difference of two images. So I can plot a histogram but I am not sure whether it is true or not? Also, I am not sure about what should be second parameter of built-in `histogram`function.

My two images are `original_result` and `output_image`. And difference of two image is `image_of_dif`.
my result:

```
image_of_dif = double(original_result) - double(output_image);
figure; histogram(image_of_dif(:), 511);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose that images are coded on `uint8`, hence integers in  $[0,\ldots,255]$. For the difference image, values can range from $0-255$ or $255-0$, the maximum span. So I would keep the negative differences by computing the histogram over all $511=255-(-255)+1$ integers in  $[-255,\ldots,255]$.

Comment: i changed second parameter of `histogram` to `511`. is it okay now?

Comment: This looks ok to me. This way, you get an histogram of all possible values in the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In your second line, casting with uint8() will change a negative value to 0. Avoid casting or change to another type that supports negative values.

Comment: i changed my code. is it ok now?